# How to copy from vim to clipboard on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I am trying copy text in vim and then i use the `*y`, but pasting it into a browser does not work. I am using ubuntu with i3 tiling manager. Can someone help with this?

Comment: You might be interested in posting questions like these to [Vi StackExchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 36):

### Answer for Ubuntu 20.04

You need to make sure clipboard is activated (which is probably not the case).

Run :
`vim --version | grep 'clipboard'`

if you get "-clipboard" then you would have to install vim again with the "clipboard" functionality.

You can do it it by installing "vim-gtk3" or "gvim".

### Solution

`sudo apt-get install vim-gtk3 -y`

With that, you will be able to copy into clipboard by typing (including the plus) `"+y`

Comment: Thank you. It was super annoying that default Vim on Ubuntu doesn't come with clipboard enabled.

Comment: There is no version of Ubuntu called "Ubuntu 20". Did you mean Ubuntu 20.04 or Ubuntu 20.10? Two versions of Ubuntu were released during 2020, one was released in April and named Ubuntu 20.04, and one was released in October and named Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: @Filmm, you'r right. I meant for all 20 versions. but it seems to be the same even for the 22 versions.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Pressing `y` from visual mode yanks (copies) text into vim's special unnamed register which is not accessible from outside vim. To copy text to the system clipboard, use `"+y`. The `"` allows you to specify the register, `+` is the register that represents the system clipboard, and you already know what `y` does.

Alternatively, to tell vim to use the `+` register as the default register, put `set clipboard=unnamedplus` in your .vimrc.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone using nvim on Ubuntu 22 arrives here, this worked for me.

1. Install `xclip`

```
sudo apt install xclip
```

2. remove default clipboard from vim

```
vim.opt.clipboard = 'unnamedplus'
```

You can now `y`/`p` in vim and then `ctrl+c`/`ctrl+p` system wide.

Answer (score 0):

`highlight + y` is a vim-specific yank command and likely won't work outside vim.

Use:

```
highlight text in vim with mouse/touchpad
<ctrl> c (or right click/copy)
select destination in new window
<ctrl> v (or right click/paste)
```

Works lots of other places as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave the content of the register on system clipboard even AFTER closing the vim, then you can use `xsel` (`sudo apt-get install xsel`) and add the following line to the `.vimrc`:

`autocmd VimLeave * call system("xsel -ib", getreg('+'))`

[works on Ubuntu 20.04 as well]